# Mix multiple citation styles in Latex

Tags: bibtex, citing

to make it clear my question in bullet points.

- The goal:

I am using a citation style that has the type:  [5]
If references are placed at the beginning of a sentence I want to write the Name of the first author: Yuang et all.

So it shall look like:
Yuang et all. [5] present an approach ...

- The idea:
  Is it possible to define a new cite-command that displays the author? So maybe:
  \citeAutorName{Yuang.2022} \cite{Yuang.2022} present an approach ...
- The question:
  Do you have an idea if this is possible?

Comment: Assuming biblatex, `\textcite` in the `numeric` style (see `30-style-numeric-biber.pdf` or `30-style-numeric-bibtex.pdf` in the documentation) does that. Number of authors is controlled by package option `maxnames=`.

Comment: Hey, thank you very much. However, I have to use the package "cite". One point that maybe doesn't get clear from my question: In the document I want to cite like "That is a problem [34]." Only if the reference stands at the beginning of a sentence I want to cite like: "Yuang et al. [20] provide a ...".

Comment: Yes, `\textcite` does the sentence beginning, according to selected package options. `cite` package is incompatible with `biblatex`; `biblatex` can sort and compress numeric citations and configure punctuation (and is programmable: loops, conditions, command building, etc).

Comment: Hey, thank you very much. Have changed to biblatex now. One problem I can't solve is the maxnames command. I have found a resource using "\printbibliography[maxnames=1]", however that doesn't seem to work. Where do I have to place that command?

Comment: Found a solution: \usepackage[mincitenames=1, maxcitenames=1]{biblatex}. Thank you for your help!!!